# Regex to identify and extract '.x-m4a' file extension from an audio filename

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to write a regular expression to identify and extract a '.x-m4a' extension from an audio file using JavaScript.

The regex I'm currently using is `/\.[0-9a-z]+$/i`

The above regex gives the TypeError:  `cannot read properties of null (reading '0')`.

The regex works fine when extracting JPG, PNG, PDF, and MP4 file extensions. In addition, I need it to identify and extract '.x-m4a' file extensions.

The code looks like below:

```
var regex = /\.[0-9a-z]+$/i
var ext = 'audio.x-m4a'.match(regex)[0]
console.log(ext)
```

Comment: What does `¡` do? If you meant a case insensitive flag, it must be an ASCII `i` letter.

Comment: There is not just a typo here to help the OP solving the issue. The pattern itself does not match, and to prevent the error the result should be checked first, apart from using `/i` instead of `/¡`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The ¡ flag that you pass to the pattern is https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/U+00A1 and does not seem to work

You are also not matching the hyphen in `.x-m4a`

Check if there is a match first before indexing into the resulting array.

```js
const regex = /\.[0-9a-z-]+$/i;
const ext = 'audio.x-m4a'.match(regex);
if (ext) console.log(ext);
```

Or if the extension cannot start or end with a hyphen

```
\.[0-9a-z]+(?:-[0-9a-z]+)*$
```

```js
const regex = /\.[0-9a-z]+(?:-[0-9a-z]+)*$/i;
const ext = 'audio.x-m4a'.match(regex);
if (ext) console.log(ext);
```